# Ubuntu 16.04 with the old "user-with-space-in-the-name conondrum

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Inherited an old ubuntu install that houses an e-commerce site.
It has an old user account with a space in it that I need to delete or at least change password or disable it as I don't know what is.
example name: stupid username

have tried these ways with no luck:
deluser "stupid username"
deluser 'stupid username'
deluser stupid\ username

but nothing works on this particular account.
Grateful for any hints on what I can do.
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to delete an old user like this is to simply go into file

```
/etc/passwd
```

and delete the line.

So, something like

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

or your favorite editor.

Comment: Everybody's favorite editor for `/etc/passwd` should be `vipw`.

Comment: You're talking religion, I'm talking security. From `man vipw` (formatting mine): "The `vipw` and `vigr` commands edits the files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, respectively. […] The programs will **set the appropriate locks to prevent file corruption.** When looking for an editor, the programs will first try the environment variable `$VISUAL`, then the environment variable `$EDITOR`, and finally the default editor, `vi(1)`." Just set your variables your way and you can go with whatever religion you want.

Comment: I use vi and it has never caused me any problems yet.